# Hibernate doesn't perform query

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I know, that similar questions have appeared many times on stackoverflow, but I cannot find a solution for my problem, because all seems to work correctly.

I want to get User from the PostgreSQL-Database with ID 5. The User exists on the database (checked with pg-Admin program).  The ID field is of type bigint. When I debug the solution I can see on the console (I am using Eclipse) that the Hibernate did load the whole mapping file and connected to the database.

I am using Hibernate 4.3 and PostgreSQL 9.3

I created a generic CRUD class to retrieve any classes I want.

I am using the following method to retrieve a object by id:

```
@Override
public T GetInstanceById(long id) 
{
    Session session = null;
    T instance = null;

    try 
    {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        instance = (T) session.get(type, id);
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {}
    finally 
    {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This is my **HibernateUtil** class:

```
package mapping.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;

    }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
   {
      return sessionFactory;
   }

   public static void shutdown()
   {
      getSessionFactory().close();
   }
}
```

In the hibernate.cfg.xml I defined following lines:

```xml
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">*******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
```

and some mappings.

My TestMethod looks like this:

```
ICrud<User> crud = new CrudBase<User>(User.class);
User user = crud.GetInstanceById(5);
String guiLanguage = user.getGuiLanguage();
```

And at the end my console output:

```
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:...hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
/////////////////////////////A lot of ressources added//////////////////////
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example]
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:42 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:42 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:43 AM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
///////////////////the next bla bla bla because of not overriding equals() for composite keys///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Sep 05, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

At the end of the console output there should now be a hibernate query which doesn't come.

What can be the solution?

Comment: You are catching the exception and not doing anything, it must be throwing some exceptions, just do `e.printStackTrace()`. I suspect, you have incompatible id type, you said your id is `BigInteger` and but you are passing `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Please show how you map User entity. If you are using annotations make sure that you didn't forget to add @Entity.

If you want to see actual queries performed by hibernate, please check if you have show_sql property in your hibernate.cfg.xml (provided snippet doesn't contain that).

Everything else looks fine.

Simplified sample of yours:

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Configuration           configuration   = new Configuration().configure(App.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
    final StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    final SessionFactory          sf              = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    final Session                 session         = sf.openSession();
    System.out.println(session.get(User.class, 5L));
    session.close();
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "users")
  public static class User {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String guiLanguage;

    public String toString() { return String.format("User#%d[guiLanguage: %s]", id, guiLanguage); }
  }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="App$User"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

db:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id BIGINT NOT NULL, guiLanguage VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO users VALUES (5, 'en');
```

Prints the following:

```
Hibernate: select app_user0_.id as id1_0_0_, app_user0_.guiLanguage as guiLangu2_0_0_ from users app_user0_ where app_user0_.id=?
User#5[guiLanguage: us]
```